# How can i quickly reset capture data in Glimpse

Tags: glimpse

Using visual studio and have a web app (MVC/API) that i want to inspect/profile using Glimpse.

I have glimpse enabled and have navigated to a specific page on a web app. so far I can see a lot of data has been collected. I now want to capture what happens when I press a button.

How do i clear previous data so glimpse only shows data related to the interaction interest?

Answer (score 0):

If the button click triggers a new page navigation, Glimpse will automatically clear the old data that you are seeing.

If it triggers an ajax request, click on the Ajax tab and select the request that was just made. All of the data in Glimpse will update to show you the info for just that ajax request.

Similarly, you can do the same thing with the history tab to see past data for past requests.